# Can I use NSTimer's scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval method for 1 day (24 hour) with or without repeats?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

User can download one file per day. Second download wait for second day. I used `NSUserDefaults` but The user change device date and download twice in a day. So can I use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:` method ? For 24 hour.

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be aware smart users can modify the `NSUserDefaults` to their liking. You may want to do some basic encryption.

Comment: @troop231 yes i used `nsuserdefault` but i want to know it is possible to do this method.? Thanks for reply.

Comment: This won't work, the likelihood of the app being open and in the foreground for a whole day is slim.

Comment: Get the time from an NTP server as a backup to using the local clock. You'll need to encrypt the next *time to download* as well.

Answer (score 2):

Stop. Think carefully. 
It's a DOWNLOAD. 
That means you will always have access to the date on the server. 
Track the server date of the last download. 
Best if tracked on the server. Meaning you need an identifier. 
But you can store it anywhere in your app's sandbox too.

I should add that most users will not be capable of accessing the iOS file system directly. Jail Breakers and Crackers are not going to pay for the app anyway.

You should store an identifier that is a salted hash that only your server can resolve. 
It's all standard web dev practices for passwords. Those techniques can be found all over the web.

Comment: i do support this approach. tracking user at back end is good option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To actually answer the original question: What you're wanting to do with an `NSTimer` won't work; the likelihood of the app being open and in the foreground for a whole day is slim.

The below code would only work if the app was in the foreground for that long, which I highly doubt will ever happen.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:86400.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
```

Comment: This looks like a comment more than an answer.

Comment: BS, answers question exactly

Comment: Read the title and question, get a grip

Comment: The question is about how to prevent users downloading more than once a day. "No" doesn't cut it.

Comment: Actually the question is this if you can read: `So can I use scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: method ? For 24 hour.`

Comment: Since when has the title mattered?

Comment: That isn't the title sherlock